# What is a "pitch" (MPITCH, VPITCH) in memory layout?

Tags: assembly, memory, raspberry-pi, gpu

I am trying to program the Raspberry PI GPU with assembler code and in order to setup the VPM (Vertex Pipeline Memory) I have to specify the "pitch". The pitch is described as follows:

*MPITCH:* Row-to-row pitch of 2D block in memory. If MPITCH is 0, selects MPITCHB from the extended pitch setup register. Otherwise, pitch = 8*2^MPTICH bytes

*VPITCH:* Row-to-row pitch of 2D block when loaded into VPM memory. Added to the Y address and Byte/Half-word sel after each row is loaded, for both horizontal and vertical modes.

I would love to link the actual documentation, but for some reason broadcoms published Videcore IV 3D Architecture Reference is no longer available under the previous address (https://www.broadcom.com/docs/support/videocore/VideoCoreIV-AG100-R.pdf)

I would be very grateful for an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *pitch* in terms of a raster is the distance (in memory location) between one row and another. For example a 100x100 bitmap with 4 bytes per pixel has a minimum pitch of 100 x 4 = 400, but could be stored in memory with a higher pitch; the address of any particular pixel is:

```
base + y * pitch + x * 4
```